# How does adding high energy density metallic nanoparticles increases the burning rate during a combustion process?

Tags: thermodynamics, rocket-science, nanoscience, combustion

I have been reading about combustion and oxidation, and I have found out that by adding metallic nanoparticles (e.g aluminium nanoparticles) the burning rate of the propellant increases while the ignition delay decreases (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S221491471830045X).

What I am trying to understand, and maybe this is a complex process, but I am looking for the general idea from an energy/thermodynamics perspective.
So my question is: how does "adding" nanoparticles "helps" the combustion process by increasing the burning rate?

I am leaning to think that the nanoparticles act as catalysts and somehow help lower the energy required for the propellant to break it's bonds and therefore release energy faster, but it is also mentioned in the article I shared before as well as in other different articles, that high energy density metallic nanoparticles, are preferred and again that's because they increase the burning rate, so I am assuming even more energy is released.

Please let me know if my reasoning is off and if you have some references I could read, i would appreciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should read this https://engineering.purdue.edu/Papers/Yetter.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Aluminum burns at a very high temperature, nanoparticles would oxidize easily, burn very hot, and release much energy. The high temperature would help ignite and burn other ingredients.